# Why "JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type " inspite of having a NoArgsConstructor?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I am getting "JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type" in spite of adding @NoArgsConstructor on the requestBodyClass. I am not able to figure out how to remove this exception

I have read most of the StackOverflow posts, But to no help

```
package com.thirdpartydefault.pojo.thirdpartydefault;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ARequestBody {

    @ValidDate
    @NotBlank
    private String timestamp;

    @NotNull
    private Long actualOrder;

    @NotBlank
    private String changedOrder;

    @NotBlank
    private String description;

    @NotNull
    private Integer statusCode;
}
```

I expected it to not throw any exception but getting this

{"errorMessage":"Could not read document: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.thirdpartydefault.pojo.thirdpartydefault.ARequestBody] from String value ('{\"actualOrder\": \"12345\", \"timestamp\": \"2019-07-14 00:30:00\", \"changedOrder\": \"10279863\", \"description\": \"Order failed\", \"statusCode\": 101}'); no single-String constructor/factory method\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4ba1b2fe; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.thirdpartydefault.pojo.thirdpartydefault.ARequestBody] from String value ('{\"actualOrder\": \"12345\", \"timestamp\": \"2019-07-14 00:30:00\", \"changedOrder\": \"10279863\", \"description\": \"Order failed\", \"statusCode\": 101}'); no single-String constructor/factory method\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4ba1b2fe; line: 1, column: 1]","cause":com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.thirdpartydefault.pojo.thirdpartydefault.ARequestBody] from String value ('{"actualOrder": "12345", "timestamp": "2019-07-14 00:30:00", "changedOrder": "10279863", "description": "Order failed", "statusCode": 101}'); no single-String constructor/factory method

"location":"ControllerExceptionHandler.handleException","stackTrace":org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.thirdpartydefault.pojo.thirdpartydefault.ARequestBody] from String value ('{"actualOrder": "12345", "timestamp": "2019-07-14 00:30:00", "changedOrder": "10279863", "description": "Order failed", "statusCode": 101}'); no single-String constructor/factory method

Comment: Your error isn't reproducible, please add edits till we can reproduce the error you see.

Comment: Your mapper gets your json as String, not as json object. Take attention on `Can not instantiate value of type [...] from String value ('{...}'); no single-String constructor/factory method`. I guess, it's something wrong with content type on the sender side. Check your caller.

Comment: Content-Type is application/json only, also I wanted to ask one more thing, do we need to have jsonproperty annotation over each field in cases where we have same json names and field name?